# Flexslider load delay and missing content

Tags: flexslider

My flexslider uses 3 posts with 'featured' category to select images for slider. I want the slider to load when page loads. The home page is a custom template that uses this code for slider...

My issues are:

1. It isn't loading when home page loads, there is a delay
2. It's not showing all 3 slides

Here is code for custom home page template for slider.

```php
.........................................................
get_header(); ?>

<div class="flex-container">
          <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
            <?php
            query_posts(array('category_name' => 'featured', 'posts_per_page' => 3));
            if(have_posts()) :
                while(have_posts()) : the_post();
            ?>
              <li>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <div class="flex-caption">
                <div class="flex-caption-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <p><?php echo get_slider_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">...</a></p>
                </div>
              </li>
            <?php
                endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_query();
            ?>
            </ul>
          </div>
</div>
```